# React Unit testing onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a Button wrapper component in which I am using mui button. I want to do the unit testing for this button wrapper component. I wrote some code but for onClick test it is falling.

**index.tsx (ButtonWrapper Component)**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
    import { ButtonProps } from '../../../model';
    
    type ConfigButtonProps ={
      // variant?: string,
      // color?: string,
      // fullWidth?: boolean,
      // type?: string
    }
    
    export const ButtonWrapper = (props: ButtonProps) => {
      const {children, onSubmit, disabled, type, onClick,  ...otherprops} = props
      console.log("button", otherprops, type);
    
      const configButton:ConfigButtonProps = {
        variant: 'contained',
        color: 'primary',
        fullWidth: true,
        type: type
      }
    
      return (
        <Button disabled={disabled} onClick={onSubmit} {...configButton}>
          {children}
        </Button>
      );
    };
```

**index.test.tsx (Button Wrapper test)**

```
import { ButtonWrapper } from "./index"
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { ButtonProps } from "../../../model";


const makeSut = (props: ButtonProps) => {
  return render(<ButtonWrapper onClick={jest.fn()} {...props} />);
};

describe("<ButtonWrapper />", () => {

  test("Button renders correctly",()=>{
    render(<ButtonWrapper />)

    const buttonElem = screen.getByRole('button')
    expect(buttonElem).toBeInTheDocument()
  })

  test("Should call onClick successfully", () => {
    const spy = jest.fn();

    const { getByRole } = makeSut({ onClick: spy });

    fireEvent.click(getByRole('button'));

   expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

**FormContainer.tsx (Parent Container)**

```
return (<form onSubmit={event=>this.onSubmit(event)}>
            {/* <div>FormContainer {JSON.stringify(this.props.states, null, 2)}</div> */}
               {this.state.fields.map((field,index)=>{
                   return <FormControl 
                    key={field.id}
                    fieldConfig={field}
                    focused={(event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=>this.fieldBlur(event,field,index)} 
                    changed={(event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=>this.fieldChange(event,field,index)} />
               })}
               <ButtonWrapper type='submit'>Submit</ButtonWrapper>
           </form>)
```

**Error**
[image]

I also want to know in order to make 90% test coverage what else I need to test ?

[![enter image description here]]

I tried this below mentioned code also but the last line fails.

```
 test("Should call onClick successfully", () => {
    const onSubmitHandler = jest.fn();
    render(<ButtonWrapper onClick={onSubmitHandler} />)
    
    const buttonElement = screen.getByRole('button');
    user.click(buttonElement)
    expect(onSubmitHandler).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1) //This line fails

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your spy function is coming in `onClick`, not the `onSubmit` prop:

```js
const { getByRole } = makeSut({ onClick: spy });
```

And your component assigns the value from `onSubmit` to `onClick`:

```js
<Button disabled={disabled} onClick={onSubmit} {...configButton}>
  {children}
</Button>
```

About the coverage - I cannot see your coverage report but what I can see in your component - there is a `disabled` prop. You should render the component with `true` and `false` values for this prop. This should give you higher coverage.